# Using Multiple SQLdatabasechain with Multipromptchain

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, openai-api, langchain

I want to know is this possible to use multiple sqldatabasechains with multipromptchain like this? OR I should try different approach?

```
table_template = """template 2"""


ans_template = """ template 1"""
prompt_infos = [
    {
        "name": "table_format",
        "description": "Good for answering questions if user asks to generate a table",
        "prompt_template": table_template
    },
    {
        "name": "ans_format",
        "description": "Good for answering questions if user don't asks for any specific format",
        "prompt_template": ans_template
    }
]

llm = OpenAI(temperature=0, model="text-davinci-003", max_tokens=1000)
sqlalchemy_url = f'sqlite:///../../../../notebooks/Chinook.db'
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(sqlalchemy_url, view_support=True)

destination_chains = {}
for p_info in prompt_infos:
    name = p_info["name"]
    prompt_template = p_info["prompt_template"]
    prompt = PromptTemplate(template=prompt_template, input_variables=["input"], validate_template=False)
    chain = SQLDatabaseChain.from_llm(llm, db, verbose=True, prompt=prompt, use_query_checker=True, top_k=20)
    destination_chains[name] = chain
default_chain = ConversationChain(llm=llm, output_key="text")

destinations = [f"{p['name']}: {p['description']}" for p in prompt_infos]
destinations_str = "\n".join(destinations)
router_template = MULTI_PROMPT_ROUTER_TEMPLATE.format(
    destinations=destinations_str
)
router_prompt = PromptTemplate(
    template=router_template,
    input_variables=["input"],
    output_parser=RouterOutputParser(),
    validate_template=False
)
router_chain = LLMRouterChain.from_llm(llm, router_prompt)
chain = MultiPromptChain(router_chain=router_chain, destination_chains=destination_chains, default_chain=default_chain, verbose=True)
print(chain.run("Give me top 5 stock codes in a table format"))
```

However I'm facing validation error with above code. The Multipromptchain giving me this error while executing

```
ValidationError: 10 validation errors for MultiPromptChain
destination_chains -> table_format -> prompt
  none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)
destination_chains -> table_format -> llm
  none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)
.
.
.
```